# Как переместить центр карты на метку при нажатии на метку yandex map api?

Tags: javascript, html, css, yandex-maps-api

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]вопрос такой. При нажатии на метку на десктопе центр карты перемещается на эту метку. Но при нажатии на метку на смартфоне да и вообще на всех маленьких разрешениях экрана центр карты съезжает куда-то вправо-вниз, оставляя метку за краем карты.

Bisurs.ru - сайт

В чем может быть проблема? Может в стилях карты или же все такм параметры yandex api?

Если есть предположения или идеи, ответьте, пожалуйста.

Вот, что я заметил, при уменьшении ширины экрана правая стороны карты фиксируется на месте, но карта сама съезжает вдругую сторону, хотя ведь должна пропорционально изменяться, а не только с одной стороны. Может все-таки дело в стилях?

Bisurs.ru - сам сайт

Спасибо за ответы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы правы, причина почти как всегда - кастомные стили.

Заблокируйте загрузку **custom-map.css** (например через ADblock) и карта с малой шириной экрана сразу начнёт центрироваться на метках как положено, хотя и возникнут другие артефакты (оформления фильтра, например).

Более конкретная причина - кастомный стиль балуна:

```
.ymaps-2-1-79-balloon-pane {
    position: static !important;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогли!!!

Comment: Эту строчку кода убрал, теперь балун не показывается на мобильных. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем дело?

Comment: Судя по всему, данный стиль разработаны не вами, а являются частью плагина или иной чужой наработкой. Этот CSS-файл меняет очень много параметров карты. И в вашем случае исправление одного может вскрывать новые и новые ошибки. Вам лучше обратиться за помощью к разработчику стиля, раз он решил изменить предлагаемый API метод отображения балуна в виде панели для узких экранов, а самостоятельно позиционировать обычный балун стилями, что сдвигает также и метку в край экрана, поскольку они связаны.